# HTML5 placeholder attribute: Chrome doesn't line-wrap in textareas

Tags: html, google-chrome, placeholder

I'm trying to use a couple of these newfangled HTML5 form attributes, and the [`placeholder`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute) attribute seemed to be a good match to get the magic going.

It works pretty good, but Chrome insists to present the whole placeholder text on one line if the textarea is to small. Other browsers like Firefox or rekonq (the only other WebKit browser that I have at my disposal ATM) line-wrap the text.

While the spec talks about linefeeds being forbidden in the placeholder attribute, it says nothing against line wrapping. Is this just something that is for the implementor to decide, is it a Chrome bug, or are the other browsers mistaken?

And, most importantly of course, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've filed this as a [**webkit bug**](http://webk.it/51290)

Next time feel free to do the same. :)

As for a workaround you can try out **[this](https://github.com/miketaylr/jQuery-html5-placeholder)** and force it to fail feature detection in webkit somehow.