# Placeholder text runs out of the textarea in Safari?

Tags: css, forms, html, safari, placeholder

You can see the problem if you open these links in safari (version 5+)

http://wufoo.com/html5/attributes/01-placeholder.html

http://jsfiddle.net/9gQZ2/

Anybody have a decent solution for making the line break properly in the textarea?

EDIT: Submitted a bug report to Apple about this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461414/html5-placeholder-attribute-chrome-doesnt-line-wrap-in-textareas

Comment: This bug is claimed to be fixed, but not exatly. See [here](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/90971)